# Music won't play via shairport-sync when connected to wifi

Tags: wifi, audio, pi-3

I have a raspberry pi 3 running Jessie with **[shairport-sync](https://github.com/mikebrady/shairport-sync)** installed.  I have a CM-108 USB sound card connected.  I have spent several days trying to figure out why I couldn't get sound out of the sound card.  I made all the suggested changes to all the configuration files, etc to ensure that the sound card is the default.  I managed to get sound out of the soundcard at most three times in two days.  However, if I paused the music (played from my iphone), I couldn't get it to start again.  If I restarted the shairport-sync service, or rebooted the Pi, the music wouldn't start.

After a couple of days of reading things on the internet, I read that the problem may be network-related.  So, I connected the Pi to ethernet to my router.  I could hear the music playing straight away.  I restarted the service and rebooted and I the music would play every time.  Repeat, everything works exactly as it should if it is connected to the ethernet cable.  If I disconnect the cable, the music will continue to play for a until I restart the Pi.

I read a couple of things about disabling the power management on the wifi which I did.  But it still won't work.

I thought it might be something to do with the drift, or resynchronisation settings, but I don't really understand what to do there.

How can I get shairport-sync to play from wifi from boot-up without first connecting to an ethernet cable?